# Text being cut off by second page

Tags: microsoft-band

I'm new to creating a band app, and I've created a basic 2 page app.

Both pages are "MSBand_ScrollingText" but on the first page the text is being cut off by the second page? Is there a way to stop this from happening?

I've attached this image to show you the problem:

[image: Image of problem]

Answer (score 0):

The clipping of the text is a firmware issue that's being investigated.

There's nothing that can be done in your app to stop it.